# Ошибка Method getText must be called from UI Thread

Tags: java, android

```
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
TextView dateFrom;
TextView dateBack;

private static String url_create_new_ticket = "http://test.devcolibri.com/create_product.php";

private static String TAG_SUCCES = "succes";


class NewBillet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Бронирование биллета");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[]args){
        dateFrom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        dateBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);

        String dateFromToDB = dateFrom.getText().toString();
        String dateBackToDB = dateBack.getText().toString();
        String pay_status = "no";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_from", dateFromToDB));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_back", dateBackToDB));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pay_status", pay_status));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_new_ticket, "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create new tickets", json.toString());
        try{
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCES);
            if (success == 1){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tickets.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Строчки

```
    String dateFromToDB = dateFrom.getText().toString();
    String dateBackToDB = dateBack.getText().toString();
```

подсвечиваются и вылазит вышеуказанная ошибка. Чем она может быть вызвана и как её исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того что вы пытаетесь достать текст из вьюх, при этом не находясь в UI -трэде. Попробуйте так

```
 new NewBillet().execute(dateFrom.getText().toString(), dateBack.getText().toString());
```

и далее

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args){

String dateFromToDB = args[0];
String dateBackToDB = args[1];
```

и тд